# Application deployed via Setup project crashes due to SQL Server CE error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, sql-server-ce

I have just create a Setup project for a C# application in VS 2008.  The setup appears to run properly on my XP SP2 Virtual Box guest machine, but when I try and run my application, it simply crashes, with only the "encountered a problem and needs to close." dialogue.  The event log lists the following error for .NET 2.0:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Event Category: None
Event ID:   5000
Date:       2011/03/06
Time:       12:21:13 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   ERISIA-XP
Description:
EventType clr20r3, P1 policymis.win.exe, P2 1.0.4082.20617, P3 4d735373, P4 system.data.sqlserverce, P5 3.5.1.0, P6 4b743b2d, P7 49f, P8 13a, P9 system.data.sqlserverce.sqlce, P10 NIL.
```

The application is built for framework 3.5 SP1, and uses the DevExpress eXpressApp framework.  The .sdf file for the application is correctly deployed and not read-only.  SQL Server CE is set up as a prerequisiste in the setup project and appears to be installed.

Any ideas on what might be wrong here?

Comment: doest it happen during installetion ?  P9 system.data.sqlserverce.sqlce suggests it might be related to the sql ce prerequisiste.

Comment: It only happens after installation, when I try and run the app.  Please see my edits for more info that has just come to light.

Comment: Have you verified that .Net 3.5 is installed?  You say it's built for 3.5 SP1, but this is a .Net 2.0 error.

Comment: Thyamine, 3.5 SP1 is installed.  The *runtime* for Framework 3.5 is still v2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 requires Windows XP SP3 - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e497988a-c93a-404c-b161-3a0b323dce24

Answer (score 0):

Must be related to dependency loading failures. Try to check if any of the dependency is failing to load with the help of fusion logs - [Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)